# Updating database table using session variables - how to?

Tags: php, session, mysqli

I'm trying to put together a basic co-ordination app for my workplace, I have secured unique logins for each staff member. Part of the app is to have a display (using Ajax to keep up to date) showing who is available or unavailable for the next case load. Simply put; I can get the database to update using *fixed* values without much difficulty, but I want the update script to be dynamic in that it will update the correct users status.

This is the snippet from the update.php script;

```
<?php
    require_once("data/connect.php");
    $user_name = $_SESSION['user_name'];     
    mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET status = 'AVAILABLE' WHERE user_name='$user_name'");    
    mysqli_close( $con );
    exit;
?>
```

As I said, above, if the value for the WHERE section is a fixed value, such as a particular users username - it works. However, once changed to the session variable, it does not. Any ideas?

UPDATE:

Ok so after following the below suggestions

```
<?php
    require_once("data/connect.php");
    session_start();
    $user_name = $_SESSION['user_name']; 
    var_dump($user_name);

    mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET status = 'ONLINE' WHERE user_name = '$user_name'"); 

    mysqli_query( $con, $query );
    var_dump( $query, $con->error );
    mysqli_close( $con );
    exit;
```

I get this;

```
NULL NULL string(0) ""
```

Some more info;
If I use the $_SESSION veriables in other ways, it works fine. Ie;

```
<?php
require_once("data/connect.php");

echo $_SESSION['user_name']; 
?>
```

This works fine to populate the various user names or what ever it is set to echo from the session, but when I try to use it as a variable for writing to the database/table, it then falls over. Even after placing 'session_start()' at the start.

***Further update***

I tried running the script in the main page, and on load it runs the script using the session variable! But still does not when running as a called file. Not sure what I've done wrong there.

Comment: have you checked before using session values .. session_start() should be in place

Comment: I've edited above showing the changes. I have added the session_start() - and have re-run the php script with the suggested debug lines in there as well. Got back; NULL NULL string(0) "" and it didn't perform the update.

Answer (score 0):

Session start is required before use the session array

```
<?php 

require_once("data/connect.php");

//you missed this
@session_start();

$user_name = $_SESSION['user_name']; 

//validate the user name
if(!empty($user_name))
{
    mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET status='AVAILABLE'
    WHERE user_name='$user_name'"); 

    mysqli_close($con);
}else{

      echo "user name is empty";

     //check your session is proper or not
      print_r($_SESSION);


}
exit;
```

Comment: I fixed the lack of the session_start() - and I got back this; NULL NULL string(0) ""

Comment: This is interesting, it comes back with user name is emptyArray ( )  Yet other uses of the $_SESSION['user_name'] do populate with the data. I copied the above code exactly, and thats what comes back. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Before any session information requests, you need to tell PHP you want to use session functionality: after the `require` line, but before the `$user_name = $_SESSION['user_name'];` line, enter `session_start();`

Comment: Wow thanks guys, wasn't expecting the help so quick! Anyway, I fixed the lack of the session_start() - and I got back this; 

NULL NULL string(0) ""

Answer (score 0):

Issue appears to have been with my SESSION carry over to the php script that I have posted, being called by my primary page. I have encorporated it into the primary page and it executes upon log in & on log out instead.